Skip or Change Default Cordova Icon from loading screen or splash screen
I’m using “Cordova 12.0.0 (cordova-lib@12.0.1)”. In this version after running app, a loading screen or splash screen with cordova default icon shows every time. Now I want to avoid or skip this page from my app or replace the cordova icon from that screen. How can I solve it?
Thanks.
This is the current loading page

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

create your own icons. check documentation: https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/commands/cordova-resources
